# Tridion GUI Custom Extensions Upgrade to 8.5 - replacing window.dialogArguments (unPublish)

Tags: cme, web8.5, gui-extensions, upgrade

We are upgrading our Tridion GUI, and we have some code that pops up a warning when you try to unpublish components that are in use.

The old code is heavily reliant on

```
 window.dialogArguments
```

including

```
window.dialogArguments.unPublishSelection 
window.dialogArguments.unPublishPipeline
window.dialogArguments.unPublishList
```

but window.dialogArguments is deprecated and has been removed from most modern browsers.  Is there an alternate way of accessing that same information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your popup should implement a View that extends one of the popup views (e.g. ExternalPopup). And you should open it using the PopupManager, which will allow you to pass those arguments to the dialog -- which can read it using its getDialogArguments() method.

**Update:** Here's an example from a modal popup window:

```
Type.registerNamespace("Example");

Example.Popup = function Popup()
{
    Tridion.OO.enableInterface(this, "Example.Popup");
    this.addInterface("Tridion.Controls.ModalPopupView");
    this.addInterface("Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.Base.Views.ViewBase");
};


Example.Popup.prototype.initialize = function Popup$initialize()
{
    var args = this.getDialogArguments();
    console.log("Dialog arguments:", args);
};

$display.registerView(Example.Popup);
```

Comment: Thank you very much Peter!  This is exactly what I need.  I also saw your helpful answer here: https://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/15546/2601 . I've confirmed that the popup is created using the PopupManager, and I can see the values on the parent window through the manager.  But I'm still at a loss on viewing them on the child window --what object has the "getDialogArguments" method on it?   Do you have a link to a sample?

Comment: I updated my answer with an example for a modal popup window. It will work the same from a non-modal popup (e.g. ExternalPopup). The getDialogArguments method is defined in Tridion.Controls.BasePopup so all of the popup controls have it.